# Find all entity fields with a specific @Annotation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I want to retrieve all my fields that have the annotation @Translatable in an entity, for example :

```
class WonderfulClass
{    
    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $aField;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $otherField;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastField;
```

In this case, I want to retrieve fields that have the @Gedmo\Translatable annotation ($aField and $otherField).

Does somebody knows how to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Doctrine Annotations Reader : https://github.com/doctrine/annotations

Or read the DocComments with the native PHP Reflection Class : http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try it since yesterday but I don't understand how to use the doctrine reader. I can retrieve all annotations on a property, but not a specific annotation like I want. Do you have an example ?

Comment: I finally understand that there is no 'magic method' to solve my problem. So with your help, I created a little script that find all my properties with a specific annotation. Thanks !

Comment: Same here. Annotations themselves are magic so why not push it a bit further? Doctrine itself surely needs this magic by itself and had to implement it somehow. Why not put it in annotations then?